# Unity: White line at camera meaning

Tags: unity

I'm a new comer to Unity. In Unity, when I click to `main camera` in Hierarchy view. I see 6 lines: one blue, one red, one green and three white. I know red/green/white lines for (x,y,z) location but I don't know what the meaning of 3 white lines is.

[image]

When I resize `scene view` I see that white lines change respectively. And at some points, three white line same with three color line as image below:

[image]
Please explain for me. Thanks :)

Comment: don't know if you just misspoke or didn't notice them in the picture, but there are 4 white lines, not 3 :P

Comment: @jhocking ah. yes. 4 lines :D just because i think "white lines" have some relationship with three color lines, so my brain works as 3 lines :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The white lines are the view frustum of the camera. It shows what is within the camera's field of vision.

The frustum can be thought of as a pyramid, with the point oriented at the camera, and the flat rectangular base pointing outwards.

This representation of a camera in virtual space is common to many 3D programs and discussions of virtual 3D space in general. In some discussions of the frustum, you will see it depicted as a trapezoidal prism (think pyramid, but with the tip cut off) because in virtual space, the camera doesn't always see all the way to the horizon (that could get very inefficient).

Thus, you get a "far clipping plane" which forms the base of the pyramid and excludes things that are too far away, and the "near clipping plane" which cuts off the tip of the pyramid, and excludes things that are too close.